# Error while opening ./uiautomatorviewer in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, adb, android-uiautomator

```
E/adb: error: cannot open '/tmp/adb.log': Permission denied
E/ddms: '/home/rishabhambre/Downloads/SDK/platform-tools/adb,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
E/adb: ADB server didn't ACK >
E/adb: * failed to start daemon *
E/adb: error: cannot connect to daemon
```

Comment: have you added ANDROID_HOME to your path?

Comment: Yes, I have added  ANDROID_HOME path

Comment: could you confirm if the path added by you is `home/rishabhambre/Downloads/SDK/platform-tools/`??
cause the uiautomatorviewer is supposed to be located at `/sdk/tools/`

Comment: ✔ ANDROID_HOME is set to "/home/rishabhambre/Downloads/SDK"
✔ JAVA_HOME is set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle."
✔ ADB exists at /home/rishabhambre/Downloads/SDK/platform-tools/adb
✔ Android exists at /home/rishabhambre/Downloads/SDK/tools/android
✔ Emulator exists at /home/rishabhambre/Downloads/SDK/tools/emulator
✔ Android Checks were successful.

Comment: @nullpointer please check the above as mention

Comment: did you try running the adb commands manually?

Comment: Yes, we tried with adb kill-server | adb start-server from terminal. Is the above ANDRIOD_HOME path mention Correct ? @nullpointer

Comment: seems like you have put in the appium doctor logs, and they suggest the ANDROID_HOME is set alright. One last thing that you can try is on the terminal move to the directory where your Appium is installed and run `adb  start-server`

Comment: @nullpointer ./uiautomatorviewer started. thanks for your support.

Comment: great! can we know what was the exact problem though

Comment: 1. cd 

2. sudo adb kill-server
3. sudo adb start server

4. sudo Downloads/SDK/platform-tools/adb devices

5. go to tools folder

6. ./uiautomator

Comment: @nullpointer I have one more doubt. please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35193800/unable-to-run-my-code-on-device

Comment: @RishabhAmbre :  better way to do that is add ../tools to your PATH environment variable and provide access to the user to avoid using sudo.
I would have a look at the other thread as well. <end of disc.>

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to get around this:

1) You could restart adb as root using `adb root`

2) You could try using `sudo chmod 666 /tmp/adb.log`

Both ways should work, but root method is probably better than changing the permissions on the file.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your system. Not better way, but it's helped me.