# Unable to Run my code on device

Tags: java, android, eclipse, selenium, appium

```
package android;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SimpleAndroidCalcTest {

    WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException{
        // Created object of DesiredCapabilities class.
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(); 
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "0227074902999561");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");         
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "5.1.1");        
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");  
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.example.mypackage"); 
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.example.mypackage.MainActivity"); 
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);        
    }

    @Test public void SKIP() 
    {   
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='SKIP']")).click();
    }
}
```

This is the following console error, and I am not able to Run the above code on device. I am running these code on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine. Eclipse version Mars.**Console error is shown as** FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setUp
    org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/adb" -s adb server is out of date.  killing... wait-for-device
    ADB server didn't ACK
    * could not start server *

```
****Console Error:****    

[TestNG] Running:
  /tmp/testng-eclipse-1773582615/testng-customsuite.xml

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setUp
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/adb" -s adb server is out of date.  killing... wait-for-device
ADB server didn't ACK
* could not start server *
) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 14.00 seconds
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
System info: host: 'rishabhambre-Lenovo-B50-70', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.19.0-25-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:156)
    at android.SimpleAndroidCalcTest.setUp(SimpleAndroidCalcTest.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:656)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:113)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177)

SKIPPED: SKIP

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@2a098129: 15 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@16b4a017: 5 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@68f7aae2: 17 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@2f410acf: 7 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@1996cd68: 6 ms

    [TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 2 ms
```

Comment: why this <br> tag at imports?

Comment: oohh sorry, I was trying to break the line ignore that <br> tag

Comment: You should start appium server..before going to run the testcase.

Comment: "adb server is out of date" first you need to fix your Android SDK issue. Update the SDK.

Comment: @SarithaG Appium server is already running

Comment: Look into the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048031/org-openqa-selenium-sessionnotcreatedexception-a-new-session-could-not-be-creat. It may b useful for u.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your sdk manager and ensure u have **api 22** installed since ur running 5.1.1 and start appium server using command prompt `adb start-server`

Answer (score 0):

There may be duplicates of adb binaries in your system

First remove all adb binaries

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove android-tools-adb
```

Then download latest version of android sdk platform tools and try running your script again..

Make sure you set android sdk home in your environment path